# TestNG configuration failure

Tags: selenium, configuration, testng

I am trying to run a simple TestNG test from the command line, it errors with a configuration failure. The same TestNG test will run from Eclipse IDE correctly. From command line it does not work. This is a severe limitation of this TestNG framework making it not very useable in a Continuous integration theme. If you plan on working with TestNG ensure you can get it running from the command line before committing to using it as your testing framework. Having to run it from Eclipse IDE is a severe limitation.

```
TestSuite_Bollosk
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 1
Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 1
```

command line syntax is:

```
java -cp "C:\correctclpath1\*;C:\correctclpath2\*" org.testng.TestNG "C:\anotherpath\TS_simpletest.xml"
```

the test looks like this:

```
package pkgTSBollosk;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class TC_Bollosk 
{
WebDriver driver;
@Parameters({"param1","param2"})
@Test
public void bollosktestmethod(String param1, String param2) throws InterruptedException 
{
    assert(true);
    System.out.println("test output for bollosk test:");
}
@BeforeTest
  public void beforeTest() throws IOException {
      driver = new FirefoxDriver(); 
      driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
          }
  @AfterMethod
  public void afterTest() {
      driver.quit();
      driver = null; 
  }
}
```

the TS_simpletest.xml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<suite name="Bollosk Test Suit" parallel="false">
 <test name="Bolluks test name">
  <parameter name="Param1" value="not - used"></parameter>
  <parameter name="Param2" value="not - used"></parameter>
    <classes>
      <class name="pkgTSBollosk.TC_Bollosk">
      <methods>
      <include name = "bollosktestmethod"></include>
      </methods>
      </class>
    </classes>
  </test> 
</suite>
```

Comment: We run testng regularly from CMD, using Ant. Never Faced an issue. Btw where is your question ?

Comment: What's the stacktrace?

Answer (score 2):

Substituting Assert.assertTrue for assert and importing org.testNG.assert fixed the problem. A trap for the newbie..... I retract my previous statement about severe limitation.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class test1 {
    public WebDriver d;
    @Parameters({"browsername","url"})
    @BeforeMethod
    public void browserselections(String broname,String URL) {

        System.out.println(broname);
        System.out.println(URL);

        if (broname.equalsIgnoreCase("ff")) {

            d = new FirefoxDriver();

        } else if (broname.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")) {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "F:\\All jars\\chromedriver.exe");
         d = new ChromeDriver();

        }

        d.manage().window().maximize();
        d.get(URL);
    }

    @Test

    public void tc1() {

        d.findElement(By.id("lst-ib")).sendKeys("testing");
    }

}

below is my xml code

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" configfailurepolicy="skip">
    <test name="Test1">
    <parameter name="browsername" value="ff"/>
    <parameter name="URL" value="https://www.google.com"/>
        <classes>
            <class name="testng.test1" />
        </classes>
    </test>

    <test name="Test2">
    <parameter name="browsername" value="chrome"></parameter>
        <classes>
            <class name="testng.test1" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite> <!-- Suite -->enter code here
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some _context_, explaining _how_ it works and _when_ to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue and i noticed that all of my jar files were in different sub folders. Move all of them in one library folder and execute with same command.

java -cp "%projectLocation%/Library/*";"%projectLocation%/target/classes/" org.testng.TestNG testng.xml

Answer (score 1):

Try TestNG config policy. Add parameter configfailurepolicy="continue" if you wish to proceed with config failures else, configfailurepolicy="skip". Example

```
  <suite name="Bollosk Test Suit" configfailurepolicy="continue">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you remove `driver.quit()` from `public void afterTest()` method,
the Configuration Failures will not come.